# When I download apps it says I need a 64-bit processor

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, 32-bit

I have a Snow Leopard OS X 10.6.8 and I cannot download apps. When I try to, it says 'this requires a 64-bit processor' (or something like that) and my processor is 32-bit. Does this mean that I'll never be able to download apps on my Mac? Is there a way to change the processor to 64-bit?

Comment: Which Mac (year and model) are you using ?

Comment: No, you won't be able to "change" your processor to 64-bits.

Comment: So I won't ever be able to download apps onto my mac?

Comment: You will not be able to install 64-bit apps, but 32-bit apps are available for a lot of stuff. Which applications are you looking at?

Comment: To my best knowledge, only the first (early 2006) model macbooks have a core duo processor. This processor is 32-bit. Every model after this one is core 2 duo or better and has a 64-bit processor. Check your model: (Apple top right, about this mac)

Comment: Are the apps you are trying to download compatible with 10.6.8? Where are you downloading them from? If your machine cannot run 10.7 or newer then many current apps will not run. However, any apps that the Mac App Store lets you download should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac allows you to replace the CPU then you could possibly buy a 64-bit processor and upgrade just that one part. Without changing that there's no practical way to run a 64-bit application on a 32-bit machine.

In the short term you'll have to find applications to download that running 32-bit environments or replace/upgrade your Mac.